# c # list comparison

Tags: c#, linq

If the data in list 1 contains one of the values in list 2, I want to add the value in list 1 to list 3.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() {"ahmet123", "aslı", "XYmehmetqwerty", "bekirtay"};

List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "ahmet", "mehmet" };

// Values ​​to be added to Listing 3: "ahmet123", "XYmehmetqwerty"
```

Comment: The two lists you have provided as examples do not contain any matching strings, meaning that list3 would be empty. Is this correct?

Comment: @John `"ahmet123"` contains `"ahmet"` so it should be included in `list3`.

Comment: @John The OP wants any string from list1 that contains any string from list2 to be added to list3.

Comment: OK, I see. That wasn't very clear from the question since it says "list 1 contains one of the values in list 2". It seems to be glossing over that complexity.

Comment: @John Agreed, I had to look at the expected output in the question to see what was actually required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new list:

```
List<string> list3 = list1
    .Where(x => list2.Any(x.Contains))
    .ToList();
```

Or if you're adding to an existing list:

```
list3.AddRange(list1.Where(x => list2.Any(x.Contains)));
```

Comment: Note that this will replace any values which already existed in list3 and not just add them. -- Not valid comment since answer update.

Comment: @TomášFilip No, the first example creates a completely new list.

Comment: Can you help us add the item in textbox1.Text next to the data in list 1 and transfer the current list to list 2?

example: i want to add ": 123" next to data in list1

Comment: @mahvettin I would post that as another question with code and expected output. I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but it seems like a completely different question.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay ` foreach (var item in listBox1.Items) { var add = TextBox1.Text; listBox2.Items.Add(item + add); } ` I was working using ListBox before, but it took too long to process large files. Now I'm trying to do it using List

Comment: @mahvettin `list2.AddRange(list1.Select(x => x + TextBox1.Text))`?